# How to get custom taxomony from post-meta in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm having some issue's trying to display the term from a custom taxonomy in WooCommerce.

Currently, I already utilise WooCommerce Product Categories, so I created a custom taxonomy called `sale_type`

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
  // Add new "Sale Type" taxonomy to Posts
  register_taxonomy('sale_type', 'product', array(
    // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
    'hierarchical' => true,
    // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => _x( 'Sale Type', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' => _x( 'Sale Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Sale Type' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Sale Type' ),
      'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Sale Type' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Sale Type:' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Sale Type' ),
      'update_item' => __( 'Update Sale Type' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Sale Type' ),
      'new_item_name' => __( 'New Sale Type Name' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'Sale Type' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'sale-type', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
      'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
      'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
    ),
  ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Then, In my failed attempt to display the term name of a custom taxonomy`sale_type` on the single product page, I used the wp_get_post_terms function similarly to how I would do with 'product_cat'.

Here's an example:

```
<span class="badge">
    <?php
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_id(), 'sale_type');
    $term = reset($terms);
    echo $term->name;
    ?>
</span>

<span class="badge"><?php $terms=wp_get_post_terms(get_the_id(),'product_cat');$term=reset($terms);echo $term->name; ?></span>
```

The output was nothing. So first, I done the obvious and checked for the 'sale_type' custom taxonomy metabox and verify that a term is selected. Then I attempted to use get_the_terms instead of wp_get_post_terms - and then also done a var dump which Debugging Output = array(0) { }

Debugging post meta for the product, I can see all the various custom fields, but I don't see the 'sale_type' taxonomy in this output.

I have never really used custom taxonomy before, so I'm now curious if that 'sale_type' might be stored differently or not stored at all in the post meta. So, is there a different approach to get the custom taxonomy terms directly?

Comment: There is not any custom taxonomy entry in `wp_post_meta` database table *(except for product attributes taxonomies that are apart)*. The link to a post (or a custom post) is made through `wp_term_relationships` database table via `object_id` column… You should add **the complete code for that custom taxonomy** in your question, if you want to get helped…

Comment: Added complete code for that custom taxonomy.

Comment: I have answered your question below… Your registered custom taxonomy for WooCommerce products works…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your WooCommerce product custom taxonomy and it works… Now I have made some little changes to your displaying code. Try the following:

```php
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'sale_type', array('fields' => 'names') );
if ( ! empty($term_names) ) {
    printf('<span class="badge">%s</span>', implode(' ', $term_names));
}
```

The code display correctly the term name(s) if they are set on a product…

- I have changed `get_the_id()` to `get_the_ID()`
- I have added `array('fields' => 'names')` as argument to `wp_get_post_terms()` to get directly the term names array,
- As a product can have multiple term names, I use `implode()` instead of `reset()`,
- Finally, I use an `IF` statement to avoid the display if there are no term names set for a product…

For display testing, I have used the following for single product pages *(on the meta section)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'single_pproduct_display_sale_type_test', 10 );
function single_pproduct_display_sale_type_test(){
    global $product, $post;
  
    $term_names = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'sale_type', array('fields' => 'names') );
    if ( ! empty($term_names) ) {
        printf('<p class="sale_type">%s: <strong>%s</strong></p>', get_taxonomy('sale_type')->labels->name, implode(' ', $term_names));
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

[image]